# What's wrong in this line asterisk* will printing in next line?

Tags: html, css

```
<p>Please fill in the required fields<p style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">*</p></p>
```

What's wrong with the above line asterisk(*) will print in next line?

I have attached the output from the results page.

[image: myOutputPage]

Comment: Paragraphs cannot contain block level elements such as other paragraphs or divs.

Comment: Change that nested paragraph tag to a span

Answer (score 0):

Rather use a `span` which is an inline tag rather than `p` which is a block tag
For more details on block and inline tags see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

```html
<p>Please fill in the required fields<span style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">*</span></p>
```

[image]

Comment: Comments should not be used to say that answer simply solved the problem, or _generally_ for thanking people _in most cases_. Rather mark this answer as accepted.